# Formatting a response in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using `GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Bitbucket` in my application built on `laravel 5.5`, where I'm facing some problem, I'm trying to retrieve list of commit details for my repository and I'm unable to use the response format. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$data = Bitbucket::api('Repositories\Commits')->all('***repo***user***', '***repo***name***', array(
        'branch' => 'master'
    ));
return $data
```

I've already tried `return response()->json(['data' => $data], 200)`

I'm getting a response which is not in JSON format:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Vary: Authorization
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 09:21:41 GMT
X-Served-By: app-139
ETag: "7b8332218b7bc6b7c4a2f50e3ab9c45c"
X-Static-Version: 476dd7889f1a
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: repository
X-Credential-Type: password
X-Render-Time: 1.31000494957
Connection: keep-alive
X-Request-Count: 141
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 20:17:03 GMT
X-Version: 476dd7889f1a
Content-Length: 71360


{"pagelen": 30, "values": [{"hash": "********9b580ff91967547d61*****", "repository": {"links": {"self": {"href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/********/*****"}, "html": {"href......
```

I mean headers data is also coming, if I use `json_decode($data)` it is gives me error which clearly shows is not a JSON. How can I format this to a proper JSON response?

**Edit:**

Please check the screenshot:

[image: biterror]

I'm getting the above code whole thing in response, which is unable to be formatted as it includes header data.

Comment: How you are calling  ? and what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 2):

**you can use Response Facade or `response()` helper function**

```
use Response;
.....
.....
return Response::json($data);
```

this would return the response as the json

Also using `response()` helper function

```
return response()->json([
    'data' => $data,
]);
```

Additionally you can set a status code also,

```
return response()->json([
    'data' => $data,
], 200);
```

Comment: Please check the questions, FIrst of all I tried `return response()->json(['data' => $data],200)` this showed me no results, when I tried your solution `Response::json($data)` it is showing me `no properties` result, I hope you are getting my point if I call a return then only I'm able to get above result.

Comment: i am not sure about this problem, as it seems the problem is with the package, and i see you have opened an issue in github. Meanwhile if i get anything , i will update here,

Comment: Thank you for your time.